# no Plot showed for an Inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse

The short code is below, but no plot is produced.  Are there any errors in my code? Thanks!

```
f[x_] = x + 2^(1/3)*x^(4/3);

g[x_] := InverseFunction[Composition[f, f]][x]

k[x_] := x^(1/3)*g'[x]/g[1]

Plot[Evaluate@k[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

Comment: `k[x]` is complex. Use `Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@k[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) is choosing the "wrong" branch for the inverse. To account for this, you can use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) to pick the branch used by [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction). For your example:

```
f[x_] := x + 2^(1/3) x^(4/3)
if = InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[f[#], #>0]&]
```

Rather than finding the inverse of `Composition[f, f]`, it will be easier for Mathematica to use `Composition[if, if]`. So:

```
g = Composition[if, if];
```

Now, unfortunately, there is an issue when using [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) on the above [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition) object, so I will use the following workaround to obtain `g'`:

```
gp = (Composition[h, h]') /. h -> if;
```

Let's do a couple quick numerical checks:

```
(* inverse check *)
Composition[f, f][g[1.]]
```

> 1.

```
(* derivative check *)
gp[1.]
10^6 (g[1. + 10^-6] - g[1.])
```

> 0.20484
>
> 0.20484

Looks good. Now, we can define `k`:

```
k[x_] := x^(1/3) gp[x]/g[1]
```

Finally, a plot:

```
Plot[k[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carl! But I have one question about 'gp = (Composition[h, h]') /. h -> if; '                                                                                              what is 'h'?  how it comes from? sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: @yewfengso Mathematica chokes on `Composition[if, if]'`, so as a workaround, I introduce the dummy variable `h`, and do `Composition[h, h]'` (which is shorthand for `Derivative[1][Composition[h, h]]`), and then substitute `if` for `h`.

Comment: Thanks for your great help! Carl!

Comment: I am still confused about the code, since I change it slightly, removing $x^{1/3}$ from k(x), but got a wired result, see below. can you take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I change the code slightly, like below in the pic, k(1)=0, but it is not actually, since the $ k(x)=\frac{(f^{-1}\circ f^{-1})'(x)}{f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(1)}>0, x\in[0,1]$.

f[x_] := x + 2^(1/3) x^(4/3)

if = InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[f[#], # > 0] &]

g = Composition[if, if];

gp = (Composition[h, h]') /. h -> if;

k[x_] := gp[x]/g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrMoR.png)

Plot[k[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

[image]